# Kafka Late Arrival message processing

Tags: apache-kafka

As New to Kafka ,  We are trying to understand about late arrival records based on the following details. Please help us on below Questions.

1. To process the late arrival records , what time parameter can be chosen to determine how long we can wait for Late arrival records ?
2. If records not arrived that time too , what would be that case ? records will be discarded for processing ?

Answer (score 2):

Consumers performing time-series analysis are the only ones that care about time; Kafka does not.

For example, say you had a device emitting metrics for some game while in airplane mode, and that would cache data locally until network reconnected.

In that case, you would collect **both** time that the events originally occurred while offline **and** the time that the records reached Kafka.

Topics are append-only, therefore your analysis is only able to project data at which it entered the system, and it's up to your analysis to discover the minimum time window of the original events.

Comment: Thanks for your response with for easy understanding explains . which timestamp parameter can be configured to make system for wait to receiving late arrival records. Watermark?

Comment: You cannot adjust the watermark and the system cannot be made to wait. In the example I gave, the only reason something "waits" is because the device is simply offline